# Ordenar imágenes por dos dígitos de su nombre

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

Tengo varios archivos tales que: IR39_MSG1-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20080204091240.png o IR39_MSG1-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20080307121242.png.

Los números finales indican cuando se tomó la foto y me gustaría poder crear varias carpetas donde pueda ordenar las fotos por horas.

Los dígitos que nos indican la hora son: IR39_MSG1-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20080204**09**1240.png o IR39_MSG1--SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20080307**12**1242.png. Siempre según los dígitos de esta posición.

```
list1 = [
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101031243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101061243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101091243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101121243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101151243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101181243.png',
    'IR39_MSG4-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20200101211243.png',
    ...
]

def get_hour 
'QUÉ FUNCIÓN ES?'

list2 = sorted(list1, key=get_hour)
```

Me gustaría saber cual es la función que tengo que poner y después como hago para crear estas carpetas y poner los archivos correspondientes.

Muchísimas gracias y perdón por las molestias.

**EDITADO**

Me gustaría añadir si es de ayuda que las horas van de las 00 a las 24 y que en realidad solo hay imágenes que tengan horas de un intérvalo de 3 horas, me explico, solo hay las horas 00, 03, 06, 09... para la creación de carpetas. Gracias

Comment: por funcion, te referis a como obtener el substring de un string?

Comment: Si, el criterio get_hour, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando por ejemplo esa misma lista, puedes obtener el substring referente a las posiciones 37 y 38 del string:

```
def get_hour(string):
    return string[37:39]
```

Con `lambda`, puedes ordenar el listado según ese substring:

```
list1.sort(key=lambda h:get_hour(h))
```

Ahora, si deseas crear directorios y mover archivos, puedes utilizar `os` y `shutil`. Un ejemplo completo y probado, podría ser:

```
from os import mkdir, path, listdir
import shutil

list1 = listdir("directorio_de_las_fotos")

def get_hour(file_name):
    return file_name[37:39]

if len(list1) == 0:
    print("No existen archivos disponibles en el directorio especificado")
else:
    for fn in list1:
        hora = get_hour(fn)
        file_directorio="directorio_de_las_fotos/"+fn
        new_directorio="nuevo_directorio/"+hora
        if not path.exists(new_directorio):
            mkdir(new_directorio)
        try:
            shutil.move(file_directorio, new_directorio)
            print("Se ha ordenado correctamente el archivo: %s " % fn)
        except OSError:
            print("El archivo %s no pudo ser ordenado" % fn)
```

En resumen, este código lista con `os.listdir`, todos los archivos y carpetas que se encuentran en la ubicación especificada (en tu caso, sería el directorio en donde se encuentran sólo las fotos que deseas ordenar). Si el directorio está vacío, se muestra en consola el mensaje "No existen archivos disponibles en el directorio especificado". Si existen archivos, itera por cada elemento de la lista de archivos, obteniendo el substring referente a la hora y, confeccionando un path con el nombre del nuevo directorio (sumándole el substring referente a la subcarpeta); si no existe ese path, lo crea. Luego, procedes a mover los archivos desde el antiguo directorio hasta el nuevo con `shutil`, lanzando una excepción si ocurre algún problema con el proceso (por ejemplo, ya existe el archivo en el nuevo directorio).

Comment: para evitar posibles errores no seria mejor utilizar una expresion regular ya que si solo se agrega o falta 1 solo caracter no devolveria correctamente la fecha ejemplo: `re.search("-([0-9]+).png",list1[0])[1]` con esto obtendriamos `20200101031243`

Comment: Muchas gracias!